Why does this python program hang the terminal when it exits on Linux or WSL?
From what I can tell, this program confuses the terminal emulation on both Linux and WSL, on both python 2 and 3.
Once the program exits, characters are no longer echoed and normal terminal function ceases.  I believe this is because the daemon thread is stuck in read(1) while the main thread exits.
You can recover the terminal by typing "reset" (which is not echoed) followed by Enter to run the reset command to reinitialize the terminal emulation.
You can avoid the problem by forcing the getchar thread to join the main thread before the main thread exits by using t2.join().
But I'd prefer to have a clean solution that just works -- any ideas?
Thanks!!!
import sys
import time
import platform
import threading

def getchar():
    import tty, termios, sys
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    try:
        tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
        ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
    print("you pressed '" + ch + "'\r")
    return ch

def getcharThread():
    while getchar() != 'q':
        time.sleep(0.1)
    print("thread exit\r")

t2 = threading.Thread(target = getcharThread)
t2.daemon = True
t2.start()

time.sleep(2)

After running this program, I expect the terminal to still work normally.  Instead, it does not echo characters (likely from the setraw() or read()).

You have created a thread that puts the terminal into raw mode, and you have made that a "daemon" thread - i.e. the program will not wait for it to complete before exiting. If the main thread exits before the getchar thread, the getchar thread will be terminated abruptly. The finally block will not run. Your program exits without restoring the terminal state, so it is still in raw mode. In raw mode, the characters you type don't appear on the screen, and are sent directly to the running program. Running the "reset" command restores the terminal to "cooked" mode.
How to solve this depends on what you're trying to do, but most likely you do not actually want to run the thread as a daemon. I don't know why you are making it a daemon thread, so I can't be more specific than that.

Maybe the question I should ask is, how can I use getchar from a thread without being forced to do a join on exit?  Is there a way?  Maybe the answer is no.  This code is for high-schoolers, so we are trying to keep it simple.  Thanks!!!

You enter a thread, mess with the terminal there, and exit the program, without giving a chance to "unmess" the terminal:
you are better of putting the behavior to restore the terminal in the main thread, before starting a secondary thread - that way, even if that thread is stuck waiting for a keypress, a finally block on the main thread, or a signal callback hook can restore the terminal behavior.
Check the docs on how to register signal handlers here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html

Yes, I totally like the idea of doing this in the main thread, rather than in the getchar function itself.  It's a bit less clean because it is spread out, but it allows me to clean up.

If you register a signal call back and an "atexit" handler (check the docs at https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html ) you can spread-out the main program without worrying about calling the finalizing code.

You can also pip install terminedia and use terminedia.inkey() which will give you whether a key is currently pressed or not, with no need to create another thread.
